# React Redux - Invariant failed: A state mutation was detected inside a dispatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm receiving this error: `Invariant failed: A state mutation was detected inside a dispatch` and can't seem to find a solution for it. I'm fetching user support tickets via an API and saving it to a state in order to display the ticket information. Here is my code:

```
const initialState: stateType = {
    User: new User(),
    SupportTickets: new SupportTickets()
}

const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: "User",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setUser: (state, {payload}) => {
            state.User = payload
        },
        setSupportTickets: (state, {payload}) => {
            state.SupportTickets.tickets = payload
        }
    }
})

export const {setUser, setSupportTickets} = userSlice.actions

export const userSelector = (state: stateType) => state.User
export const userSupportTicketsSelector = (state: stateType) => state.SupportTickets

export function fetchSupportTickets(userId: string, token: string) {
    return async (dispatch: AppDispatch) => {
        return await fetch(API_URL, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
            }
        }).then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) { throw response }
            return response.json()
        }).then(json => {
            dispatch(setSupportTickets(json))
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log('Failed to fetch support tickets', error);
        })
    }
}

interface stateType {
    User: User
    SupportTickets: SupportTickets
}
```

```
export class SupportTickets {
    tickets: SupportTicket[] = []
}

export class SupportTicket {
    id: number = 0
    type: string = ""
    subject: string = ""
    priority: string = ""
    status: string = ""
    created_at: string = ""
    updated_at: string = ""
}
```

I've tried changing/moving things around without any success. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the problem.  It looks like you're creating some kind of classes to store your data, and putting those in the Redux state:

```js
const initialState: stateType = {
    User: new User(),
    SupportTickets: new SupportTickets()
}
```

[**You should never put class instances or other non-serializable values into the Redux state**](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#do-not-put-non-serializable-values-in-state-or-actions).  Instead, you should [use plain JS objects, arrays, and primitives](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#use-plain-javascript-objects-for-state).

The good news is that you're using Redux Toolkit's `createSlice` API, which will let you write "mutating" update logic that becomes a safe and correct immutable update.  But, you need to be using plain JS objects in our state for that to work correctly.

I'd strongly recommend reading through the two tutorials in the Redux core docs:

- [The "Redux Essentials" tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts), which teaches beginners "how to use Redux, the right way", using our latest recommended tools and practices.
- [The "Redux Fundamentals" tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-1-overview), which teaches "how Redux works" from the bottom up.

Comment: Thank you! Weird thing is the User state works perfectly fine, but I was unable to do that with the support tickets. I changed it to an object and it worked like a charm. The state with just the user was already written and I thought maybe appending a new class object was the way to go, but I guess not.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I'm new to TypeScript and JavaScript and was hoping to save some typing through instantiation.